# How to input a String for a URL in Java?

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup

I am building a web crawler to get search results from craigslist for a school project.
I am trying to take user input for a search query and add it to complete a URL.

This function is not necessary for me to submit the project but I would like to know how to make this function work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String incomSite1 = "\"https://houston.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=";
    System.out.println("What would you like to search for?");
    Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String srchItem = userIn.nextLine();
    String comSite = incomSite1 + srchItem + "\"";

    final String url = "https://houston.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=computer";

    try {
        final Document results = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        System.out.println(results.outerHtml());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This part of the code that I should scrape the site for the search results and display the HTML.

If I just copy/paste a URL from browser into the "final String url = " without all of the other code then it works fine.

However, when I use the Scanner, incomSite1, srchItem & comSite to fill "final String url" I get the following errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed URL: "https://houston.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=computer"
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:136)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:76)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
    at CraigCrawl.main(CraigCrawl.java:21)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "https://houston.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=computer"
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:134)
```

Comment: why does the url need to be quoted? well it doesn't and shouldn't - removal will lead to sucess

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I assumed that the URL had to be in quotes because they were needed when I copy/paste the URL from browser instead of taking user input.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Remove `Double Qoutes` from Start and End of Url. as `url` is already a String you dont need to add those quotes